# Error al crear una tabla por _token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla User y una tabla Entrada, la cual es para que un usuario compre una entrada para ir de visita a un jardín botánico.

Los datos del ticket:

```
Schema::create('entradas', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->date('fecha');
            $table->unsignedInteger('persona'); // Quien ha comprado la entrada.
            $table->foreign('persona')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

También hay que tener en cuenta que la tabla `User` tendrá una variable 'saldo', que indicara cuanto dinero le queda a esa persona. Comprar una entrada cuesta 7€.

Formulario para comprar la entrada:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

@Logged()
@include('partials.errors')
<div align="center" class="panel panel-default">
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Nueva reserva") }} </h1>
    <h2>Recuerda que una entrada son 7€<br>Tienes actualmente {{Auth::user()->saldo}}€</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" action="../reserva">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Indique la fecha") }}
            </label>
            <input id="fecha" style="width:150px" type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" value="{{ old('fecha') }}"/>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="addPlanta" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Reservar entrada") }}
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
@else
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute" style="color:#FF0000"> {{ __("Debes haber iniciado sesión para crear una reserva") }} </h1>
@endLogged
@endsection
```

Una vez rellenado, vamos al siguiente sitio de web.php:

```
Route::post('reserva','EntradaController@confirmar');
```

Y esto nos lleva a la siguiente función:

```
public function confirmar(EntradaRequest $r){
        if(Auth::user()->saldo<7)
            return back()->with('message', ['msg', __('No tienes suficiente dinero')]);
        elseif($r->fecha>=now()->toDateString()){
            $r->merge(['persona' => auth()->id()]);
            Entrada::create($r->input());
            Auth::user()->saldo-=7;
            Auth::user()->save();
            return back()->with('message', ['success', __('Reserva realizada con exito. Se han descontado 7€ de tu saldo')]);
        }
        return back()->with('message', ['msg', __('No puede reservar para una fecha pasada')]);
    }
```

Durante esta función, se utiliza EntradaRequest.php, el cual tiene este codigo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EntradaRequest extends FormRequest{
    public function authorize()    {
        return auth()->check();
    }
    public function rules(){
        return [
            'fecha' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Pero al intentar ejecutar el cuestionario, me topo con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado que el error esta concretamente en `Entrada::create($r->input());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar en su modelo `Entrada` debería tener asignado en el `array` `$fillable` las columnas de su tabla que asignará masivamente como es el caso del método `create`

```
protected $fillable = ['fecha', 'persona'];
```

En segundo lugar en su controlador ya el `FormRequest` , *(EntradaRequest)*  retorna un `array` con los datos si estos pasaron las validaciones correspondientes. Entonces debería acceder a `$r->all()` y pasar al método `Create` ,pero además desea añadir la persona de forma manual, podría hacerlo añadiendo esa propiedad con **+**  y Ojo el id del usuario `logueado` se obtiene diferente.

```
elseif($r->fecha>=now()->toDateString()){
        Entrada::create($r->all() +  ['persona' => auth()->user()->id()]);
        Auth::user()->saldo-=7;
        Auth::user()->save();
        return back()->with('message', ['success', __('Reserva realizada con exito. Se han descontado 7€ de tu saldo')]);
 }
```

Comment: Listo, ya he conseguido que no de error.